# Readability of Camel Case

Tags: faces

I am writing Latex Style Files and want to improve the appearance of Camel Case Variables and Functions.  What kind of elisp function can I write to enhance readability.

Have been directed to `glasses.el`.  Rather than install another minor-mode to my configuration, I would like to take out the part that sets capital letters to a different colour.

Looking at the code I have identified `glasses-face` and `glasses-make-overlay`.  But I need help to construct a function or two to enable and disable the colour functionality.

Have been working with the following function

```
(defun change-face-for-camel-case (face)
  "Change the face of capital letters in CamelCase words throughout the buffer.
FACE is the face to apply to the capital letters."
  (interactive "MFace for CamelCase letters: ")
  (let ((case-fold-search nil))
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (re-search-forward "\\b\\([A-Z][a-z0-9]*\\)\\([A-Z][a-z0-9]*\\)\\b" nil t)
        (add-text-properties (match-beginning 1) (match-end 1) `(face ,face))
        (add-text-properties (match-beginning 2) (match-end 2) `(face ,face)))
      (font-lock-fontify-buffer))))

;; Bind the function to a key for easy use, e.g., F5
(global-set-key (kbd "<f5>") (lambda () (interactive) (change-face-for-camel-case 'font-lock-variable-name-face)))
```

Comment: `M-x glasses-mode`

Comment: I do not like working with glasses because I would not know what is real and what is imitation, particularly when making changes.  For reading display purposes it seems good enough, but not for things beyond that.

Comment: Did you look at its customize group?

Comment: Did not look that detail. You are referring to the use of colours.  Would prefer to make a small function for that rather than enabling yet another minor mode.

Comment: Welcome!  If you don't like `glasses-mode`, you'll need to be more specific about what help you need.  In particular, please post functions that you have created but need help finishing.  Otherwise, this question risks turning into a "please code this thing for me"-style post, which does not generally go down well here.

Comment: I want to change the face for colouring capital letters.  And be able to swittch the functionality on and off.

Comment: You can enable `glasses-mode`, set `glasses-separator` to the empty string, and set `glasses-face` to the name of the face you want to use, for example `'underline`. This won't require you to install anything external, as `glasses` is included with Emacs.